# Phone connected to adb via Wi-Fi disconnects immediately when USB cable is pulled

Tags: usb, adb, android-wifi

I'm developing on a Linux system with Android Studio 3.1.3 and  connected my device to adb via Wi-Fi:

ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ !622
adb usb
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ !623
adb devices
List of devices attached 
FA7BJ1A01528    device

ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ !624
adb tcpip 5555
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ !625
adb connect 192.168.42.4
connected to 192.168.42.4:5555
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
FA7BJ1A01528    device
192.168.42.4:5555   device

Now I remove the USB cable and check the connected devices:

ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached

First of all, why am I seeing two devices attached while the cable is attached? Second, why is the phone not appearing in the list after I pull the USB cable? The phone is running Android 8.1.0.

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding concepts. Command *adb devices* will list  only devices avaible for debugging eg. emulators or devices connected via usb, and not devices connected to Wifi

Comment: FractalBob..Do you got the solution?. If not remove the "duplicate question" so that someone can answer the question.

Comment: No. How do I remove the "duplicate question"?